# Check the last row and not remove it also hide button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my markup like this

```
<div class="language-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control required" id="language-first" name="language-first" aria-required="true">
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="CS">Czech</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
        </select>                           
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control required" id="language-second" name="language-second" aria-required="true">
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="CS">Czech</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
        </select>                           
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn add-new-row">Add New Row</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn delete-row">Delete New Row</button>
</div>
```

Here I want to duplicate the row(clone). So for that I made the jQuery like this

```
var row = jQuery('.language-wrapper');
jQuery('.add-new-row').click(function() {
    var parent = jQuery('div.language-wrapper').last();
    parent.clone(true).insertAfter(parent); 
    var wrapperLength = jQuery('div.language-wrapper').length;
    if( wrapperLength > 1 ) {
        jQuery('.delete-row').show();
    }
});
```

Here you can see I am adding  another button called as delete new row when there is more then a row is present. This one is doing fine. Now I want to work that delete row button so that it will remove the last row. and the button will be hide when there will be only one row is present. So for that I made the jQuery like this

```
jQuery('.delete-row').click(function() {
    var parent = jQuery('div.language-wrapper').last();
    var Length = jQuery('div.language-wrapper').length;
    jQuery(parent).remove();
    if(Length < 2) {
        jQuery('.delete-language').hide();
    }
    console.log(Length);
})
```

But this one is not removing the delete row button even there is a single row is present. It is also removing the last row by doing click. So how to make the jquery so that it will not remove the last row and the button will    be hide if there is a single row is present.

Answer (score 0):

Your button can be defined by it's `class="btn delete-row"` so can be selected by using `.btn.delete-row`.

The `Length` is being checked before the row is removed, so the button needs to be hidden when there are two rows (which is about to become one row).

```
if(Length === 2) {
    jQuery('.btn.delete-row').hide();
}
```